# java.lang.NullPointerException when using Facebook Module on Android

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, trigger.io

Using the latest Facebook (v2.12) module with Trigger.io (platform v2.2.14), attempting to "Login with Facebook" causes the app to crash and shows the following in the log:

```
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013): Process: com.myapp, PID: 7013
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.myapp/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2986)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.facebook.LoginActivity$2.onBackgroundProcessingStarted(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.notifyBackgroundProcessingStart(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.access$2(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.authorize(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.startOrContinueAuth(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onResume(Unknown Source)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1257)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6076)
07-20 12:10:46.834: E/AndroidRuntime(7013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)
```

I have double-checked App ID, Key Hash, and relevant settings on Facebook, but the error keeps occurring. Has anyone experienced the same issue and how did you fix it?

Comment: Which Forge platform version are you on?

Comment: Does it still crash with older versions of the Facebook module? e.g. v2.11?

Comment: Just pushed v2.13 of the Facebook module, can you give it a try please? Thank you!

Comment: Older version of module are fine. I will give the new version a try. Thanks.

Comment: Facebook Module v2.13 works perfectly. It has also fixed a login issue when the Facebook App is not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Trigger.io Facebook Module v2.13](https://trigger.io/modules/facebook/current/docs/index.html) fixed the login issues on Android.